# How to change background color every n-seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So a while back I think i saw an effect on some site that was transitioning between different background colors (changing background colors).

The color changed like every 2-3 seconds.

The transitions were pretty smooth as well. I found it pretty cool.

I'm redesigning my services website and would like to add that effect to my site.

There are 2 variables that need to be controlled: time and color.

P.S. Not trying to get anyone to write the code for me, but could you please refer me to some links where I can find out about this effect.

Would be great if you could tell me the name of this effect and the library it exists in.

Comment: google css background color animation

Comment: See also [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ode9v18k/) that shows you some @keyframes in combo with the js to slow down timing via click. Hope that helps!

```
.body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    animation-name: colorChange;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    text-align: center;
}

@keyframes colorChange {
    0% {
        background: red;    
    }
    20% {
        background: blue;    
    }
    40% {
        background: green;    
    }
    60% {
        background: orange;    
    }
    80% {
        background: purple;    
    }
    100% {
        background: red;    
    }
}

.button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

---

```
$( ".button" ).on( "click", function () {
    $( ".body" ).css( "animation-duration", "20s" ) 
})
```

---

***Edit***
Added snippet.

```js
$( ".button" ).on( "click", function () {
  $( ".body" ).css( "animation-duration", "20s" ) 
})
```

```css
.body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 1000px;
        animation-name: colorChange;
        animation-duration: 10s;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    @keyframes colorChange {
        0% {
            background: red;    
        }
        20% {
            background: blue;    
        }
        40% {
            background: green;    
        }
        60% {
            background: orange;    
        }
        80% {
            background: purple;    
        }
        100% {
            background: red;    
        }
    }
    
    .button {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="body">
    <button class="button">Change Timing</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks. This is the best and most simplest solution. However I am having a problem figuring out the timing between the transitions. it seems that the animation-duration argument in the JS function does not seem to work because I've played around with it changing the time value but it simply does not make a difference on the time of the animaiton.

Comment: The only way I seem to change the time of transition between 2 colors is by changing the css ( i increase the percentage between any 2 colors.) This works but it will only allow me to have less colors in my animation. I want to add more colors.

Comment: You are most welcome. Here is an updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ode9v18k/4/) which tackles changing timing a little more thoroughly. I have also added a button which tackles changing color on a click event. Does that help you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes it does! Didn't need the buttons though as I'm looking to add the feature to the background of my site!  Thanks ALOT! :D

Comment: Could you upvote my question if you think it was a genuine question and met stackoverflow standards. Need to improve my reputation a bit! :)

Answer (score 0):

To change your website background color in a defined time interval you can follow the bellow link.
http://www.cakephpexample.com/html/add-gradient-effect-to-your-website-by-javascript/

Where a complete example given with source code.

Comment: This didn't work. However i found a solution with animation keyframes! Thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly do it with CSS3 animation keyframes.

Take a look at this [Fun With Pulsing Background Colors in CSS3](http://designshack.net/articles/css/fun-with-pulsing-background-colors-in-css3/).

Comment: Its about time i start learning CSS3. Turns out the solution was with animation keyframes! Thanks a lot man! :D 
Could you upvote my question if you think it was a valid question which met stackoverflow standards? Thanks. :)